# Python Print(item) doesn't show any output

Tags: python, regex

On the first `print(item)` I got the result i wanted. But on the second `print(item)`, (the regex to find an IP) doesn't print anything. What am I doing wrong?

The code basically is to search in a text file all of the IP in it.
Then I was trying to add a string before the ip is shown.

#### txt file:

```
                               IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A
==========================================================================================
IP_ADDRESS      MAC_ADDRESS        VLAN  PORT                 TYPE    TTL(10 Sec) TUNNEL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.0.1     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  -     -                    LOCAL   2160
192.168.0.2       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   -                    LOCAL 2160
192.168.0.3       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103  -                    LOCAL  2160
192.168.0.4     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c657:1/45            DYNAMIC 1031
192.168.0.5     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c657:1/46            DYNAMIC 877
192.168.0.6     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c657:1/45            DYNAMIC 2149
192.168.0.7    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   -                    LOCAL   2160

====================================================================================================
                        IP Arp Extn - ITF Omn-toll-A
====================================================================================================
MULTICAST-MAC-FLOODING    AGING(Minutes)       ARP-THRESHOLD
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
N/A                       360                  N/A

c: customer vid   u: untagged-traffic
7 out of 68 ARP entries displayed
acli.pl: Displayed Record Count = 8
ARPs on TX-NNI: Current = 0, re-ARP count = 0
==========================================================================================
                                  IP Arp - ITF Omn-b
==========================================================================================
IP_ADDRESS      MAC_ADDRESS        VLAN  PORT                 TYPE    TTL(10 Sec) TUNNEL
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.0.8     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  -     -                    LOCAL   2160
192.168.0.9       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   -                    LOCAL 2160
192.168.0.10       ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   -                    LOCAL2160
192.168.0.11      ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/45           DYNAMIC1015
192.168.0.12    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/46            DYNAMIC 878
192.168.0.13    ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/16            DYNAMIC 873
192.168.0.14     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/17            DYNAMIC 873
192.168.0.15     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/45            DYNAMIC1017
192.168.0.16     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/46            DYNAMIC 873
192.168.0.17     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  103   c658:1/46            DYNAMIC 876

----
```

I wanted the output to be like this:

```
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.1                     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.2       
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.3       
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.4     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.5    
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.6     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.7


IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.8     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.9       
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.10       
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.11     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.12   
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.13    
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.14     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.15     
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.16   
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.17
```

Here is my code:

```py
with open(Sw0, 'r') as f:
     for line1 in f:

          #if in_file:
                line1 = line1.split(' ')

                for item in line1:
                    if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+\_[a-zA-Z]+', item):
                      match = re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+\_[a-zA-Z]+', item)
                      data0.append(match.group(0))

                for item in f:
               # section header
                    match = re.search(r'IP Arp [^Extn-]*-\s*(\w+)', item)
                    if match is not None:
                       section = match.group(0)
                       print(item)
            #print(section)
                       continue

                       for item in f:
                           match = re.search(r'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', item)
                           print(item)
                   
                           if match is not None:
                              data5.append({'section': section, 'ip': match.group(0)})
                              print(item)
                              for d in data5:
                                  print('{} {}'.format(d['section'], d['ip']))
```

Comment: Do you read `f` twice? You have two `for item in f:`s. That seems to be the problem. Also , no need to repeat `re.search`, use `m = re.search(...)` and then `if m: print(m.group())`.

Comment: Do you mean i shouldnt have a for item in f: after 'continue'. he doesnt print anyth though

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a representative input sample. Ideally, replace the code which reads from a file with a simpler, minimal snippet which just processes a static string which doesn't do what you want. See also the [help] and in particular the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Is this the actual indentation of your code? The ``continue`` is unguarded, all code after it on the same indentation level will be skipped.

Comment: yes it is ,the indentation level doesnt prompt any error , what do u mean of continue being unguarded?

Comment: ``continue`` aborts the current loop iteration and immediately starts the next (it "jumps back" to the ``for item in f:`` line). If you use ``continue`` without guarding it with an ``if``, none of the code after it runs, ever. Why do you use ``continue`` here?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi It was an advice for other user to replace my code like that but doesnt work as i wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to read your file `f` twice. Simply iterate it once, if you find a header, update the current header and find all IP addresses under it. We can still use `continue` here to go back to `for line in f` when we find a header, since no IP addresses need to be searched on the current line. Also we don't need need to keep calling `re.search`. Simply check if it isn't `None` first, then call `.group(0)`.

Also I think `^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` is a more suitable pattern for searching IPv4 addresses, since every octet can only have numbers between 0 and 255. I also just used the `IP Arp .*` pattern to find headers, since it seems that the headers need to start with `IP Arp`, and any character/s can be after it, hence the `.*`.

Here's what you can do instead:

```
from re import search

with open("data.txt") as f:

    header = None
    for line in f:
        header_match = search(r'IP Arp .*', line)
        if header_match:
            header = header_match.group(0)
            continue

        ip_address = search(r'^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}', line)
        if ip_address:
            print(f"{header}-{ip_address.group(0)}")
```

**Output:**

```
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.1
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.2
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.3
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.4
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.5
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.6
IP Arp - ITF Omn-tool-A-192.168.0.7
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.8
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.9
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.10
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.11
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.12
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.13
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.14
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.15
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.16
IP Arp - ITF Omn-b-192.168.0.17
```

Comment: it works fine but how could i add that the final output to variable called data5?

Comment: alright thank you, i have another question it doesnt let me split on '..Omn-b-192' because its a string so i cant export it and add it in 2 different cells in a csv file. Is there anyway i could split like '...Omn-b', '192.168.0.17' so i have to different strings to work on csv files?